# Android Studio adding rxjava library

Tags: java, android, rx-java

Consider following project structure:

```
MainProject
-.idea
-.grandle
-src
-SubProject
--libs //I created this folder manually
---rxjava-core-0.16.0-sources.jar
--src
---main //+ all the sources
--build.grandle
--SubProject.iml
-build.grandle
-//other files
```

I downloaded the .jar from http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.netflix.rxjava%22%20AND%20a%3A%22rxjava-core%22 (sources.jar) - but I also tried others

Then I created lib folder in the SubProject and then put the .jar to it.

In Android Studio I rightclicked on the library and selected "Add as Library..."
with level: "Project Library" and module: "SubProject".

The rxjava uses package name "rx".I have some code implemented that imports this package:

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Observer;
import rx.Subscription;
import rx.subscriptions.Subscriptions;
```

When building the project following error occure:

```
Gradle: package rx does not exist
Gradle: package rx.util.functions does not exist
Gradle: cannot find symbol class Action1
...
```

I found that it is required to put a line to SubProject/build.grandle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'libs/rxjava-core-0.16.0-sources.jar' //added line
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
}
```

but then it throws:

```
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':SubProject'.
> The description libs/rxjava-core-0.16.0-sources.jar is invalid
```

I tried to moving the .jar around the project structure but so far no luck.

How do I properly add a 3rd party library to the project? Is it ok that I created the "libs" folder myself?

Comment: Yes you have to create `libs` folder yourself. Have a look at [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716) answer.

Comment: @Mac: thank you. But I am probably missing something. I did create the libs folder i did copy the .jar file there but it does NOT WORK. Maybe the libs folder is in wrong place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [importing jar libraries into android-studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735923/importing-jar-libraries-into-android-studio)

Comment: Ok, first observation is that when compilig files "compile files 'libs/rxjava-core-0.16.0-sources.jar' " is the correct syntax. Didn`t fix the issue though

Comment: i found this import for rx java on a pluralsight course  compile "com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-core:0.16.1" what is the difference??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you could just try adding:

`compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.16.1'`

and dont forget to click "Sync Project With Gradle Files" button.

Answer (score 8):

The latest dependency for gradle should be:

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.10'
```

Ref [this link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: If you are using rxandroid then
https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.reactivex/rxandroid/

Answer (score 0):

first you need to add the code `compile 'libs/rxjava-core-0.16.0-sources.jar'`
you can choose the library in the libs folder and find the "Synchronize + library name" to rebuild it ,then you can use the library.
hope can help you