# How do I start using RxJava for Android Studio?

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

I have heard many Android developers use RxJava for reactive programming, however the concept is still quite new to me. I want to start learning to use RxJava and have gone to the GitHub page but don't know how to "install" or start using it. The GitHub manual barely makes sense to me.

I am using Android Studio on Ubuntu 14.04. Can someone guide me on how I should start?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio adding rxjava library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060607/android-studio-adding-rxjava-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use RxJava library, you should define it in `gradle`. So, you should have something like this in your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
 }
```

I would recommend you using `RxAndroid` instead of regular `RxJava`simply because you have some stuff adjusted to Android apps and its life life cycles.