# How to create .jar with Gradle (Android Studio) with dependencies

Tags: android, jar, gradle

I'd like to make a .jar file from my Android library project. I know Gradle itself creates in build/intermediates/bundles/release/ classes.jar file which contains all my project classes. However I'd like to obtain a .jar which includes all third party libraries I use in project.

How to do it ? How to write such gradle task ?

I'd really like to ommit creating .aar file due to I don't use any res in the project which normally makes creating .jar impossible. I want it .jar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [importing jar libraries into android-studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735923/importing-jar-libraries-into-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

android does not have only java files, it contains assets, resources, third party projects, So there is no need to create jar for android projects. However Recently, Google introduced the **aar** that can be used in android projects. read more **[here](http://jayway.github.io/maven-android-plugin/aar-mojo.html)**

Comment: Yes, this is possible solution but I pointed I don't want .aar. The solution for aar is here: http://www.flexlabs.org/2013/06/using-local-aar-android-library-packages-in-gradle-builds