# How I can download the source code and javadoc for both of javax.mail.jar and activation.jar?

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I made import libraries for javax.mail.jar and activation .jar and additional.jar and when i try send mail error tells me that source not found for DataHandler.

Comment: have you copied your libraries in libs folder & added it into build path?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the source code at runtime.  The error you're getting when you try to send mail is because it can't find the DataHandler class, which means you don't have activation.jar available in your runtime CLASSPATH.

Comment: how to set CLASSPATH in linux mint because i use android studio on linux mint.

Comment: I have no idea, but if you're actually running the application in android studio I'm sure the documentation will tell you how to include additional jar files in the classpath that your application runs with.

Comment: i really include additional.jar but it tell me classdeferror

Comment: You included all three of the jar files?  Then I have no idea.  You need an android studio expert.  Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735923/importing-jar-libraries-into-android-studio) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779959/android-studio-importing-external-library-jar) help?