# Addons folder missing in Android SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to android development. I was going through this [Guide](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Robolectric-Installation-for-Unit-Testing#setting-up-for-eclipse) to setup a roboelectric test project. In one of the steps, we need to add maps.jar as dependency to the project. The maps.jar is usually located inside addons folder in SDK directory.When i tried to locate the maps.jar in my SDK directory, I found that addons folder is not there. Is there any way to get it ?

I am using Eclipse Juno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally figured out the reason , why i dont have the addons folder inside my SDK directory. It is because, i have not downloaded even a single Google API's of any version of android in Android SDK Manager.Finally fixed it by downloading Google API's for the required android version.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There was another question similar to this:

[importing jar libraries into android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735923/importing-jar-libraries-into-android-studio)

To quote ant2009 from that question:

> This was actually fixed with the new updated 0.2.8 version. All I did was create a new directory called 'libs' Dragged the jar file into it. Right click the jar file 'Add as library'. This will expand the jar file. Entered this into the build.gradle file 'dependencies { compile files('libs/jtwitter.jar')}. Entered the import statement to bring the classes into my source file. Everything worked fine. –  ant2009 Sep 19 '13 at 6:33

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry this was not useful. I had to add maps.jar, which is usually found in addons folder. But in my case, the addons folder itself is missing in my SDK directory