# How to add third-part library with javadoc to gradle build script for Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jar, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project in Android Studio and two third-party libraries provided as jar files with javadoc in separate jar-file. So I have 4 external files:

1. lib1.jar
2. lib1-javadoc.jar
3. lib2.jar
4. lib2-javadoc.jar

Javadoc.jar files contain some html files with project documentation generated with JavaDoc util.

When I try to compile apk-file I get an error:

> Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK /Users/****/Projects/****/app/build/outputs/apk/****-debug-unaligned.apk
>
> Path in archive: allclasses-frame.html

In my build.gradle I declare project dependencies as follow:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

If I get it right I don't need to compile javadoc files, but I want Android Studio to show me documentation when I writing code.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In summary;

```
-> new -> module
-> import jar/AAR package
-> import select the jar file to import
-> click ok -> done
```

For more info, please follow this link this link [click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32087539/3678308), or [youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpuJPoXkFG4)