# Picasso and httpClient cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

Does anyone face this problem before ? Picasso and httpClient cannot be resolved.

**Gradle Build Error**

> Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'app'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
> >     Could not find org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2.
> >          Searched in the following locations:
> >              file:/C:/Users/tongws/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/jbundle/util/osgi/wrapped/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client/4.1.2/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client-4.1.2.pom
> >              file:/C:/Users/tongws/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/jbundle/util/osgi/wrapped/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client/4.1.2/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client-4.1.2.jar
> >              file:/C:/Users/tongws/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/jbundle/util/osgi/wrapped/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client/4.1.2/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client-4.1.2.pom
> >              file:/C:/Users/tongws/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/jbundle/util/osgi/wrapped/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client/4.1.2/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client-4.1.2.jar
> >          Required by:
> >              :app:unspecified
> >     Could not find com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0.
> >          Searched in the following locations:
> >              file:/C:/Users/tongws/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/squareup/picasso/picasso/2.4.0/picasso-2.4.0.pom
> >              file:/C:/Users/tongws/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/squareup/picasso/picasso/2.4.0/picasso-2.4.0.jar
> >              file:/C:/Users/tongws/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/squareup/picasso/picasso/2.4.0/picasso-2.4.0.pom
> >              file:/C:/Users/tongws/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/squareup/picasso/picasso/2.4.0/picasso-2.4.0.jar
> >          Required by:
> >              :app:unspecified

**Gradle Sync**

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0
<a href="openFile">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2
<a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
Information:The project encoding (windows-1252) has been reset to the encoding specified in the Gradle build files (UTF-8).
Mismatching encodings can lead to serious bugs.
<a href="http://tools.android.com/knownissues/encoding">More Info...</a>
```

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter() // or mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

**Edited**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'

}


buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter() // or mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

**Gradle Sync Error**

```
Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2
<a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

**Gradle Build Error**

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/tongws/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/jbundle/util/osgi/wrapped/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client/4.1.2/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client-4.1.2.pom
         file:/C:/Users/tongws/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/jbundle/util/osgi/wrapped/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client/4.1.2/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client-4.1.2.jar
         file:/C:/Users/tongws/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/jbundle/util/osgi/wrapped/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client/4.1.2/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client-4.1.2.pom
         file:/C:/Users/tongws/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/jbundle/util/osgi/wrapped/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client/4.1.2/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client-4.1.2.jar
     Required by:
         :app:unspecified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your build gradle  add **useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'**

```
android{
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Comment: can you please check again

Comment: add the code  defaultConfig { multiDexEnabled true }

Comment: do I need to remove this ?  compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'

Comment: multiDexEnabled true  checked?

Comment: still faced same problem means remove that org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.cli‌​ent:4.1.2  instead of that try library

Comment: DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams()); cannot resolved

Comment: downlaod add add jar from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpclient421jar.htm

Comment: httpclient-4.2.1.jar

Comment: downloaded. what should add now ?

Comment: to add jar in android studio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735923/importing-jar-libraries-into-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient is being depricated so better to use Volley or also you can visit okhttp, by the way if you still want to use http client then there is option just you have to include legacy in your android block in graddle app file

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Picasso use web services so once you will solve this picasso will work correctly, for detail on picasso please visit

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/picasso-android-tutorial-picasso-image-loader-library/

Comment: can you please check again

Comment: As I think you should follow the picasso tutorial from link posted above according to my best. use legacy and restart your project. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two problems :
1) add this in  /project/build.gradle

```
   allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }    
}
```

2) You can do the above mentioned

```
android{
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```